# User prompt between tasks in ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to throw a user prompt at task level hence, I cannot use var_prompt. For this I have a tiny shell script as follow which is running `read`  command to catch user response and I am calling it from command module but its not working.

```
cat question.sh
read -r -p "Are you sure? [y/N] " response
case "$response" in
    [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
        echo "do_something"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "do_something_else"
        ;;
esac
```

My playbook:

```
---
  - hosts: localhost
    tasks:

      - name: "Do you want to proceed?"
        command: bash question.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to use var_prompt. Split your play into few, and place var_prompt in between.

Was:

```
- hosts: foo
  tasks:
    - name: task1
      debug:
    - name: asking for foo
      debug:
    - name: task2
      debug:
```

Become:

```
- hosts: foo
  tasks:
    - name: task1
      debug:
- hosts: foo
  vars_prompt:
    - name: foo
      prompt: bar
  tasks:
    - name: task2
      debug:
```